# speech recognition not working from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, speech-recognition

I have an app that uses the ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent. It works fine when i call startActivityForResult from an Activity and the corresponding onActivityResult is in the same Activity.

My problem is i have another app that uses fragments. If i call startActivityForResult from the Fragment, the speech box does not appear.

What i have tried:

I've tried overridding onActivityResult in the parent Activity and then call getActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
This just launches the intent and the onActivityForResult in the Activity class executes.

i've tried various combinations from the following post.

[onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

This is the code i have at the moment and the logs. Has anyone any suggestions?

NB i have the following permissions in the manifest too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

.

Parent Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.e(TAG, "inside onActivityForResult in parent. requestCode = " + requestCode + "resultCode = " + requestCode + " data = " + data );
    }
```

.

Fragment class:

```
private static final int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

    // Create an intent that can start the Speech Recognizer activity
    private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
        Log.e(TAG, "inside displaySpeechRecognizer() and speechRequestCode = " + SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
// Start the activity, the intent will be populated with the speech text
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    // This callback is invoked when the Speech Recognizer returns.
// This is where you process the intent and extract the speech text from the intent.
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.e(TAG, "inside onActivityForResult in child fragment. requestCode = " + requestCode + " resultCode = " + resultCode);

        if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            String spokenText = results.get(0);
            // Do something with spokenText
            Log.e(TAG, "spokenText = " + spokenText);
            etCommentEditText.append(" " + spokenText);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

.

Logs:

```
    05-02 14:57:37.012 14414-14414/com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall E/AlertDetailsFragment: inside displaySpeechRecognizer() and speechRequestCode = 0
05-02 14:57:37.072 14414-14414/com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall E/AlertDetailsFragment: inside onActivityForResult in child fragment. requestCode = 0 resultCode = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call `recognizer.startListening(speechIntent);` and for stoping `recognizer.stopListening();`

Now it works in fragments.

Suppose, you want to initialize speech recognizer when button clicked call above methods.

Comment: Hey that worked great thanks. I didn't find anything on the net about tutorials for this way of doing it. One question, how do i get the native dialog box to appear that tells the user the spech recogntion is actually happening? The other way of doing it has a box with a microphone in the middle.

Comment: Just Create a custom dialog. Below is the XML code I followed.<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_voice_listen"
        android:id="@+id/voice_img_listen"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Listening..."
        android:gravity="center"/>

Comment: after dialog.show(); call recognizer.startListening(speechIntent); and then after closing dialog call recognizer.stopListening();

Comment: Ah ok, i thought there may be a native thing i could call. Ok thanks for your help